# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined with a IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working my way through Learning jQuery 4th Edition (PacktPub publishing), trying out one of it's exercises where i have to create new plugin methods called .slideFadeIn() and .slideFadeOut(),combining the opacity animations of .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() with the
height animations of .slideDown() and .slideUp().

This is my current code

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.slides={
    slideIn:function(){
      $(this).fadeIn().slideDown();
    },
    slideOut:function(){
      $(this).fadeOut().slideUp();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$('h1').click(function(){
  $(this).slides.slideOut();
});
```

yet when i click on `<h1>`, i get the error message,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
```

I've also tried

```
(function($) {
  var elem=$(this);
  $.fn.slides={
    slideIn:function(){
      elem.fadeIn().slideDown();
    },
    slideOut:function(){
      elem.fadeOut().slideUp();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

to see if the error was because `$(this)` was referring to a different context, but i am still getting the same error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
```

EDIT:I've tried editing the code to

```
$('h1').fadeOut().slideUp();
```

and it works, so the issue lies with `$(this)`, i just don't see what exactly is the problem with `$(this)`

Could someone kindly point out my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: It really looks like `this === $.fn.slides` in the functions `slideIn` and `slideOut`, try with just `console.log(this)` and see what it tells you. Reasoning: method `bar` in `foo.bar` will have `this === foo` when invoked as `foo.bar()`

Comment: Hi Paul, THanks for replying, i've tried console.log(this), and it logs to the console, the h1 element. I.e <h1>Title</h1>, it returns Object {slideIn: function, slideOut: function} when i put console.log(this) in the function instead of the click handler.

Comment: When I tried, `$.fn.foo = {bar: function () {console.log(this);}}; $(document.body).foo.bar(); // Object {bar: function}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating your plugin is a little different than I would, as the "this" is the "fn.slides" scope 'this' - thus, it errors out.  I was able to solve your issue by passing the context of the "this" you want -- which is the 'h1' by using 'call'. With "call" (and "apply), I can call the function and pass in the 'this' context I want.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.slides={
    slideIn:function(){
      $(this).fadeIn().slideDown();
    },
    slideOut:function(){
      $(this).fadeOut().slideUp();
    }
  }
})(jQuery);

$('h1').click(function(){
  $(this).slides.slideOut.call(this);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by ** "this" is the "fn.slides" scope 'this' ** ?? I'm creating the plugin by following the examples as given in the book, how would you create a plugin?

Comment: I apologize for not being succinct enough. When you call slideOut(with your current code), slides is acting $this - the element, but inside the method "slideOut", the $this is referring to the scope of the object $.fn.slides. Console out "this" within that method. You'll see that it dumps the actual slides object.